# Updating Versions using maven-release-plugin

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-release-plugin

I am using maven 3.0.4 in combination with cvs and jenkins.

I have a multi-module project with a main pom and some modules.

For a correct versioning i set some environment variables in jenkins.

The first step is that i have a pre-build-step in jenkins that executes an maven goal:

```
--batch-mode release:update-versions -DdevelopmentVersion=${ACTUAL_VERSION}${BUILD_NUMBER}-SNAPSHOT
```

Now maven is updating the Version of my parent pom and the connection from the modules to the parent pom. this is all working fine, but i have some internal dependencies between the modules which are not updated. how can i force maven to update them too?

Example:

--Parent
   -- Module1
   -- Module2

In module 2 there is an dependency to module1, e.g.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>module2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

After the release:update-versions the parent pom and the modules are updated but the dependency now still refers to the old version. is there any way to update this dependency version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest and best solution (in my opinion) is to use :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>module2</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

instead of hard coded version. May be you can use the following as well:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>module2</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```